# Time out during the connection to local server from physical device

Tags: android, apache, port, wifi, ip-address

I downloaded Apache 2.2 from [here](https://httpd.apache.org/) I know that this is old version but anyway I need it. Then I launched Android emulator and tried to access to server and it worked. I used 10.0.2.2 IP address with 8080 port.

Next, when I try to connect to server using PC on which I launched the server, it works if I provide IPv4 address of PC for example 192.154.1.23:8080.

Well, when I try to connect to server using my physical device (my mobile phone) I can't do that even if I try IPv4 address of my PC with 8080 port. It just tells me about time out.

What should I do to connect to server from my phone?

P.s. I use same WI-FI network on both devices

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Well first of all you need to set type of your connection to private and make sure that this is trusted network, for example your home network or your own WI-FI. But you also can do it with public network but this is too risky!!!

Then go to Firewall settings and allow Apache application to communicate with other devices. Choose it in the table of allowed app and features and check the box for private network, then press OK. I recommend to restart Apache server.

That's it! Now you can connect to server using IP address of your PC, on which you installed Apache server, from any device like other PC or mobile phone but you have to be in same local network. If you want to access your server globally you need to ask your ISP (Internet Service Provider) to get static IP address to make it visible in global network.